# Using PHP to print an image

Tags: php, printing, gd, printers

Unfortunately searching this on Google is very difficult due to the print() function. I have a form that posts to a page that creates an image based on the submitted values. I need to make it so that after creating the image it opens the print dialogue.

Should be simple enough, but it's late and I'm lazy -_-

Comment: wow, it's eaaaaaassssyyyyyy. But, sorry, I'm lazy too.

Comment: -1 for 'it's late and I'm lazy'. It's amateurish comments like that that make me not want to answer questions like this at all.

Answer (score 3):

PHP itself can't do this, afterall it is a server side language and what you're asking to do is client side functionality.

Perhaps Javascript's [window.print() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.print) is what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

I would say after it creates the image it should have a javascript function to open the print dialogue.  Something like:

```
<?php
if($imageisdone){
echo "<script>window.print();</script>";
}
?>
```